# Looping Through UIScrollView and Setting UImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to implement lazy loading of images in a UIScrollView but I am having some problems trying to set the images.

The user scrolls and I use the following to detect what the next view tag should be. I then want to be able to loop through the corresponding UIView and set its UIImageView image.

The following is not working and I was hoping someone could help me to correct it.

```
for (UIView *subview in self._scrolViewForEffects.subviews){

         for (UIImageView *view in subview.subviews){

             if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){

                 if(view.tag == currentPage){

                     if(view.image == nil){

                         [view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Theme1.png"]];

                     }

                 }

             }

         }


    }
```

Comment: When you say 'it's not working', what do you mean? Also, try putting some NSLog() calls to see what is and what isn't being called

Comment: Why not use a collection view?

Comment: The problem I have is that the images are edited before placing them into the UIImageView. I have found that with a UICollectionView, the images are not saved when they are scrolled off screen so you end up having to edit them again when they appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it wasn't to do with the code above. It turns out that I wasn't setting the tag on the UIImageView when I was creating it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've been there. I sure feel foolish when I find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough information to say what problem you can have but I suggest you to execute in debugger window a command

```
po [self._scrolViewForEffects recursiveDescription]
```

to check your view hierarchy at runtime.